# Visual Studio 2012 not deploying SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2012, apps-development

I am trying to deploy a workflow (list or site) to an app web via a SharePoint Hosted App solution in Visual Studio 2012. Once I deploy the app, I noticed that the workflow isn't available in the list's workflow settings. I have installed Workflow Manager 1.0 and configured SharePoint to use it. I verified that there are no errors in ULS log during deployment. Has anyone come across this behavior before?

I have attached a screenshot of the properties of Workflow.xaml for reference.

[image]

Comment: Have you followed this guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharatgupta/archive/2013/04/27/sharepoint-2013-app-workflow-with-custom-task-outcomes-in-o365.aspx ?