# VS2012 won't deploy my SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio-2012, app

Well, I have got the same problem as [this guy](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73895/visual-studio-2012-not-deploying-sharepoint-2013-workflow) with the equally titled thread.

I want to add a SharePoint 2013 Workflow to my App Web. It is a list Workflow. Workflow Manager and Service Bus are installed and configured correctly.

When I create a Workflow and want to debug/deploy the App, the Workflow is not listed as Workflow in the List.

I don't know why, I don't know if its a development or a server configuration issue.

Has someone had the same problem, but solved it?

(Everything is programmed in Visual Studio 2012. Lists, and Workflows, too)

Thank you,
Loki

Comment: Did you add the workflow to a feature? do you get any error message?

Comment: In Apps, you can't add Workflows to the Features. Because of the Feature Scope. It is simply impossible. But the Workflows will be (usually) deployed correctly, even if it's not added to a Feature. If I deploy my App to an Office 365 Developer Site, the Workflow is deployed correctly, and works. Same App deployed on my Server wont work. I have no idea why.